# Connecting Hive with python

Tags: python, hive

I want to connect hive using python.
I am using Anaconda to get the module. Can anyone suggest me the correct syntax for connecting hive with python, I have the username and password for the hive database I wish to pick data from.

Comment: impyla could be useful, but I'm not sure if it forces you to use kerberos as authentication protocol. Take a look at https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/blob/master/impala/hiveserver2.py#L739

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Pyhive module

The command to connect is :-

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="YOUR_HIVE_HOST", port=PORT, username="YOU")
```

Hope this helps with the error you are still getting - [Git link](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/161)

Comment: The pyhive module is not available for the win-64 channels, i tried to get   the module by using the command conda install pyhive, but i was thrown    the same error about the package not found in win-64 channels. I will   have to turn to pyspark i believe, any help @Abhijeetk431 will be   appreciated.

Comment: I tried the following from pyhive import hive hive_connection= hive.connect(host='XXXXX',port=XXX,authMechanism='KERBEROS',user='XXX',password='XXXX!'), but i got the error "TTransportException: Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'"

Comment: Please see the link in answer. It might help you.